# Using factors in ggplot and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to make a ggplot  with some data, filling the dots with a factor variable. I'll write here a small example to explain myself.

```
drap = tibble(id = c("S1", "S2", "S3" , "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8"), 
              ret =c (123, 555, 763, 113, 415, 121, 221, 531),
              cod = c(1, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5, 8))

#here the "cod" column is converted to a factor with 9 levels (0 to 8).
drap$cod = factor(drap$cod, levels = c(0:8), ordered = TRUE)


plot = ggplot(drap) + geom_count(mapping=aes(x= id, y=ret, fill = cod))
ggplotly(plot)
```

The factor() function works well (I can see all the levels) but the problem is after.
When I  make the plot, the legend has only values presented in the database (so 1,3,5,8). I want to show a legend with all the factor levels (0:8). I discovered that using the function levels() I can save the factor levels, but I don't know what to do next.

Of course this is a small example and everything should work also in shiny.

**EDIT:**
For those interested in the problem, I've found a solution with `ggplot` but if you want to use `ggplotly()` it doesn't work. The @duck solution works fine as long as you have the same data as input. If you want to change for example the variables, it doesn't work anymore (at least without a lot of if conditions). So a "reactive" solution is to use `DROP=FALSE` inside `ggplot`. Unfortunately for now `plotly` doesn't support this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(drap) + geom_count(mapping=aes(x= id, y=ret, fill = cod))+
  scale_fill_discrete(limits=factor(c(0:8)))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you it works. But now I have another problem. This solution works for that data, but in my app x and y are not fixed and I change them. So for example if I want to show a continous data instead of that factor data (or simply another factor data with different levels) it doesn't work. So ggplot should take the levels directly from "drap". The problem is only with ggplot because with tmap() the legend is correctly showed (it takes levels directly from the data without specifying them manually). Any ideas?

Comment: I've found that this can be done in ggplot using DROP=FALSE and it works, but then plotly doesn't support this function so for now my problem doesn't have a solution. Thanks however.

Comment: @FabioDR I see. If you consider this answer in any sense helped, consider accepting/upvoting it. Kind regards!